# PageSummary is not working in kartik GridView in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I want to show page summary in kartik gridView. My code is as follows:

```
$columns = [
    ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn', 'width'=>'50px'],

    [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
        'width'=>'50px',
        'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
        },
        'detail'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {

            return Yii::$app->runAction('invoice/detaildebtors', ['model' => $model['branch_id']]);
        },

        'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'], 
        'expandOneOnly'=>true
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'branch_name', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left', 

    ],        

    [
        'attribute'=>'0-60 days', 
        'label' => "0-60 days", 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',            
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true,
    ],

];

echo GridView::widget([
    'columns'=>$columns,
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'floatHeader'=>true,        
    'floatHeaderOptions'=>['top'=>'50'],
    'floatOverflowContainer' => true,
    'responsiveWrap'=>false,
    'panel' => [
        'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading'=>'<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Debtors\' Report</h3>',
        'footer'=>false,
    ],

    'toolbar' => [],
]);
```

I want page summary. How can I get it.
This grid also have a nested grid in it.

Also I want to give column width and allow to text wrap in that column.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'showPageSummary' => true
```

http://demos.krajee.com/grid#page-summary

most likely this is the reason.